# GitHub: is it possible to create a pull request with selected (not all) commits in a branch and push it into another branch?

Tags: git, github

Suppose I have two branches: master and feature. In feature, I made several commits (say, five commits). What I want is to select two of these five commits, move these two commits into a pull request and them push this request to master. Is it doable in GitHub web interface? I saw the solutions with git cherry-pic, but just wondering if it is possible in GitHub UI.

Comment: Cherry pick command?

Comment: Mujeebu, as I mentined above, I am aware of git cherry-pic and just wondering if it is possible in GitHub UI, but thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I think you must create a new Branch for this 2 commits. Than you can create a pull request for this Branch.

I can not think of anything else ...

Comment: Hmm, seem to be a crutch. Anyway, if I create a new branch, how would I add these two commits from my feature branch to this newly created branch?

Comment: With a Cherry-Pick: `git cherry-pick <Commit ID>`

When you the new Branch from the Feature Branch create, the Commits are existing. In the Feature Branch can you the Commits revert. `git revert <Commit ID>`

Comment: Thank you, Daniel.

Answer (score 1):

I will mention about other two options, what you can do apart from creating the branch.

let's say, you have following commits and you wanted firs three commits only,

```
git branch feature_x
  |----------> commit 1 x
  |----------> commit 2 x
  |----------> commit 3 x
  |----------> commit 4
  |----------> commit 5
```

Legend:*x - mean commit selection.

**Rebase**

One option is to use the rebase, `git rebase -i HEAD~<no_of_commits>` and then push it to the origin.

If you want to pick let's say 1, 3 and 5 not in sequence in that case just do `git rebase -i HEAD` and it will take you interactive session, you can select the commit what you want.

---

Another option is.

**Cherry-pick**

```
git cherry-pick <your_commit_id>
```